# QTextStream writes wrong data to file

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qfile, qtextstream

I try to read and write from same file but get strange behavior. Here is example code :

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_textEdit_textChanged();

private:
    QFile *File;
    QTextStream *FileStream;
    QString TextFromFile;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    File = new QFile;
    File->setFileName("test.txt");
    File->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
    FileStream = new QTextStream(File);

    TextFromFile = FileStream->readAll();
    ui->textEdit->setText(TextFromFile);

    File->close();
    File->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    *FileStream << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    FileStream->flush();
}
```

So when i type for example this :
[image]
file will change to this :
[image]
but i need this :
[image]
My aim is to overwrite file every time when i type characters to textedit.

Comment: There's no "strange behavior" here at all, this is what you'd expect a stream operator to do.

Comment: @MrEricSir, Can you explain, please?

Comment: This was the 37000th question in the qt tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need rewrite file every time then try to do this without pointers. Something like:

```
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{    
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();  
    QFile file("test.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        qDebug() << "failed open";
    else
    {
        QTextStream out(&file);
        out << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    }
    qDebug() << "The slow operation took" << timer.elapsed() << "milliseconds";
}
```

`QFile` destructor will close file at the end of slot.

Output in my case:

```
The slow operation took 0 milliseconds 
The slow operation took 0 milliseconds
```

Of course with big data it will be slower, but I think that it is normal approach.

Probably you thought that `QIODevice::Truncate` should do the trick, but it is wrong. From doc:

> If possible, the device is truncated before it is opened. All earlier
>   contents of the device are lost.

But in your code it does not work because you use same stream, you does not open your file every time, you just append new words every time. And `flush()` just flushes any buffered data waiting to be written to the device.

Comment: I'd worry about correctness first.  Fast code that doesn't work isn't all that useful.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Unfortunately I didn't understand you. What's wrong? My code works, I tested it a few minutes ago, it's fine.

Comment: @Chernobyl Your code is perfect.  I was responding the performance comment.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, sorry, I understood :) Just thought that it is for me because of lack of `@username`

Comment: @9vashrotebal There are few approaches to clear file. For example close and open file without `QIODevice::Append` flag, delete file and create it again, but in your code you open file one time and every time write new data without deleting old, so your output is incorrect. In my code, I open file without `QIODevice::Append` flag every time, so all old data deletes and I write something new, to the "clear" file.